# ModelForm field included even when not in fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And the admin:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
...

@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
    fields = ('name',)
    create_fields = ('name', 'confirm_name')

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super().get_fields(request, obj)

        if not obj:
            fields = self.create_fields

        return fields
```

Everything works fine. But when you add a record and then try to edit it, I get the error "Please correct the error below." without showing any field errors. I checked the form errors and it says *confirm_name* should not be empty. Why is it still being included if it's not added in *fields*?

Comment: Because it is a field of the form. You might want to use it, well, for confirmation. If you want to make it optional, you can write `required=False` in the `forms.CharField(..)`

Comment: But that makes the field not required and users can ignore it. It's a required field.

Comment: So do you want it required when creating and not required when editing?

Comment: Exactly. You will have enter the name twice when creating to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `add_form` instead of `get_fields`.

In your example

```py
class CreateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    confirm_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #.... your validation logic 

class UpdateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and in your `admin.py`

```py
@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestForm
    add_form = CreateTest

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during test creation
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults['form'] = self.add_form
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
```

Credits from [django.contrib.auth.admin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py)

Answer (score 0):

Field for admin form are from TestForm

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

You can use:

```
class CreateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        field = ('name', 'confirm_name')

class UpdateTestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        field = ('name',)

@admin.register(Test)
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            kwargs['form'] = UpdateTestForm
        else:
            kwargs['form'] = CreateTestForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to give you an up vote but I am new and unable to vote yet.